# TypeError Uncaught [object Object] thrownr Uncaught [object Object] thrown

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

I'm getting this error while testing `ng test --code-coverage true`:

> Error : Uncaught [object Object] thrown

Spec.ts file:

```
 import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject, tick, fakeAsync } from 
 '@angular/core/testing';
 import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injectable, 
 DebugElement, 
 Inject } from '@angular/core';
 import {CustomComponent} from './custom-component';
 describe('CustomComponent', () => {
 let component: CustomComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomComponent>;
 beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, CookieModule.forRoot(), 
 HttpClientModule, HttpModule],
 declarations: [CustomComponent],
 providers: [],
 schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
 }).compileComponents();
 }));
 beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
tick();
}));
it('is form invalid when empty', fakeAsync(() => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomComponent);
const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.form.valid).toBeFalsy();
}));
});
```

Comment: Please show the code that displays this error, post it here formatted as code or create a snippet and share it with Stackoverflow members. If you would like them to spend time on your problem, please spend some of your time to post a question that can be responsibly answered.

Comment: Please try running the tests with `ng test --source-map=false` and see if it gives you a more useful error message.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Couldn't find out any working solution. Did you find out any @muka.gergely

Comment: @Muqarram to be honest, I did not pay too much attention to this question (now 3 and a half years ago), as it was poorly presented back then - it would've been a task in itself to understand the context and the exact problem. The case might be somewhat different now, but still: for me it would be complex to rebuild the mentioned environment. Sorry, right now I have no time to do any of that.